# How to insert images to specific excel file cells

Tags: python, excel, insert

I need to create an excel file and add images to certain cells so in each row I add two images in A1 and B1. I need to do this for around 150 images by copying and pasting them?

Can someone tell me how to do that using python script automatically by just defining the images path and the excel file path and the number of the images in the folder?

Comment: I am not sure if that is helpful: 'import cv2
import os

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images
folder="directory/folder path"'

Answer (score 0):

Using the xlsxwriter library

```
import xlsxwriter

# creates an excel sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('images.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'your-image-name.png')

workbook.close()
```

See the [xlsxwriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#insert_image) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but my problem is that , I have 1000 thousand images they have the same name but different endings for example: filename1.jpg , filename2.jpg...till filename1000.jpg. So, I know how to insert one image. but I do not know how to create a loop to insert 1000 thousand images without the need of copying and pasting 1000 times.

Comment: you can add the worksheet.insert_image() method in a loop `for i in range(1,1001): worksheet.insert_image("A"+i, "filename{:0>4}.jpg".format(i))`

Comment: Thank you I will try implementing that. But where can I add the path of where my images are? or the name of my image?

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlsxwriter

# creates an excel sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('your_save_path.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i in range(10):
    worksheet.insert_image('B{}'.format(i), 'filename{}.jpg'.format(i))

workbook.close()
```

Comment: This answer is mostly the same that was given years ago. Please, when answering old question, be sure to bring something new that wasn't already said back in the time. And to clarify how your answer is different and better than the existing ones. Besides, "code only" answers are discouraged.